# Using Dev C++, Can't get CURL to work, 'Missing libcurl.o'

Tags: c, curl, libcurl, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h> 
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
char *url = "http://example.com/";
//FILE *Site_html;

curl = curl_easy_init();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
if (curl)
{   
    Site_html = fopen("page.txt","wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEINFO, NULL);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, Site_html);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}   
fclose(Site_html);
return 0;
}
```

I Have this code in Dev C++, I've installed curl accordingly (copied the bins to the right place, includes, etc)

I've also linked the libs to the project.

Some commands added

And I'm getting this error every time..

```
>D:\Program Files\DevC++\Trabalhos\Makefile.win [Error] No rule to make target '../MinGW32/lib/libcurl.o', needed by 'Scam.exe'.  Stop.
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQbMZ.jpg  - Images for everything and error.

There isn't a libcurl.o, the program is just refusing to work and I have no idea why, I've looked everywhere on the internet, tried everything, makefiles from other-working programs (those gave me the same error), everything, if anyone knows how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probably need something similar to `-lcurl` on your link command line.

Comment: I've added that already :/ Check the imgur i posted, -lcurl is on

Comment: I can't access imgur.com from work.

Comment: No problems, i've added -lcurl -lws2_32 -lwinmm, maybe it's a problem in the makefile? i don't get it why there is an error on the libcurl.o...

Comment: Have you tried moving your linking commands `-lcurl -lws2_32 -lwinmm` to the commands when calling the linker? Additional commands to your compiler should be empty or at least have the additional includes, but since your compiler does not give you an include-error it seems fine.

Comment: Just tried it, still outputs the same problem.

Comment: What's in your makefile?

Comment: @melpomene this is: http://imgur.com/ORQ66Qe
Dev C++ created it and i haven't touched it

Comment: @Daniel That Makefile doesn't make sense (bogus libcurl object files, `-l` options in `CFLAGS`, etc.), so my guess is this is a Dev-C++ configuration issue.

Comment: @melpomene how can i solve the issue? i can't seem to find any sample makefiles that i can adapt to this problem